# error private within this context c++

Tags: c++

I think I have been working on this code too long. Anyway here is whats happening.

header file (scope of the project forbids changing public)

```
#ifndef FRACTION_
#define FRACTION_

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

class Fraction
{
  private:

    int num,denom;


  public:

    // Construct fraction from numerator and denominator
    //
    Fraction( int = 0, int = 1 );

    // Construct fraction by copying existing fraction
    //
    Fraction( const Fraction& );

    // Assign into fraction by copying existing fraction
    //
    Fraction& operator=( const Fraction& );

    // Return true if fraction is valid (non-zero denominator)
    //
    bool IsValid() const;

    // Return value of numerator
    //
    int Numerator() const;

    // Return value of denominator
    //
    int Denominator() const;

    // Input/Output operations
    //
    friend istream& operator>>( istream&, Fraction& );
    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream&, const Fraction& );
};

// Comparative operations
//
bool operator==( const Fraction&, const Fraction& );
bool operator!=( const Fraction&, const Fraction& );
bool operator< ( const Fraction&, const Fraction& );
bool operator<=( const Fraction&, const Fraction& );
bool operator> ( const Fraction&, const Fraction& );
bool operator>=( const Fraction&, const Fraction& );

// Arithmetic operations
//
Fraction operator+( const Fraction&, const Fraction& );
Fraction operator-( const Fraction&, const Fraction& );
Fraction operator*( const Fraction&, const Fraction& );
Fraction operator/( const Fraction&, const Fraction& );

#endif
```

I am trying to overload the + operator, here is my code for that:

```
Fraction operator+(const Fraction &f1, const Fraction &f2)
{
    return(((f1.num*f2.denom)+(f1.denom*f2.num)),(f1.denom*f2.denom));
}
```

I get an error about referencing num and denom as private variable, I am just having a hard time figuring out how to correct that problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Numerator()` instead of `num` and `Denominator()` instead of `denom`. Your operator is not a member, nor a friend, so it can't access private members.

The other option would be to

- make it a *member* (but making an operator that can be a free function a member has several disadvantages, including that you can't say `5 + frac`, only `frac + 5`)
- make it a `friend`, (but making it a friend when it doesn't have to be increases the number of things that have access to the class not through its interface, leading to increased code maintenance)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least four ways to solve this problem:

1. Change `f1.num` to `f1.Numerator()`, etc.; that's what accessors are for.
2. Make all of the arithmetic operators friends of the class. Not unreasonable.
3. Change your `operator+(const Fraction&, const Fraction&)` a member function (which then takes only one argument); this sometimes complicates things, and us usually not a good approach.
4. Add a member `operator+=(const Fraction& rhs)` which adds `rhs` to `*this`, and then use that operator to implement your non-member `operator+(const Fraction& lhs, const Fraction& rhs)` as `return Fraction(lhs) += rhs;`. This is the most general solution.